# Transferring Textbox data to my ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two textboxes with userinput, of which I need to transfer the data to my ViewModel. I tried looking around how to do this by binding it to a button (as the transfer is supposed to take place upon a buttonclick), but most advice to use bindings. However, to use bindings you have to declare properties in the ViewModel (afaik), but as these strings are used to create a new object, holding properties for them would be all but ideal because the two textboxes might expand to over 10 in the future. I've also tried messing around with `CommandParameter` but I only seem to be able to declare one.

So for clarification:
How do I transfer the contents of two (or more) textboxes to the corresponding ViewModel so I can create a new Object with them?

Edit:
In addition I'd also like to be able to reset the `Text=` field to be empty once the method handling the data has succesfully completed.

The View

```
<TextBox Name="UI1"/>
<TextBox Name="UI2"/>
<Button Source="*ImageSource*" Command="{Binding CallCreateObject}"/>
```

and the ModelView

```
private void OnCallCreateObject()
{
   Object newObject = new Object(UI1, UI2, false)
}
```

This is a general example of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Can you sir show us some code, please?(xml and viewmodel)

Comment: @Misters Added an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Is that what you meant?

Comment: For clarification, you said that you can have 1 to N textboxes created dynamically?? Or do you have a defined number or textboxes in your view?

Comment: @Misters as of now, there is a set amount of textboxes of two. However, in the future it might be extended to more, but this will require some of the code to be extended as well. The amount of textboxes is NOT dynamically determined. Does that provide sufficient clarification?

Comment: What is wrong with adding more properties to the ViewModel?  The purpose of the ViewModel is to provide the View with access to the data in the Model.  The View is only there to present the data (and access to the behaviours) in the appropriate format.

Comment: @MikeofSST Because the property fields are only ever used a single time if a new instance will be created, which quite possibly could be never, or every 10 minutes, depending on how extensive the user will be using the program's capabilities. The VM that would be needing these properties, already has a lot of code in it, Properties, Commands, Methods, etc. I do not want to have to write up to 100 lines of code to declare properties if I can do without. And whether or not I can do without is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @Ciphra It sounds like you need a `CreateObjectViewModel` to handle the construction of new Model objects.  This would have a different set of properties reflecting the (little-used) data that you're struggling with.  I.e. it represents a different view of the model: a different ViewModel.  It would separate the concerns of creating new objects, from those of displaying existent objects (in your current ViewModel).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data from UI to ViewModel on Button Click than there is no reason to use binding. Binding is mainly used to sync data between UI and underlying models.

Still if you want only that then on `button_click` event you can do something like this.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.Property1 = textBox1.Text;
        model.Property2 = textBox2.Text;

        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

That will solve your issue. But this approach is not recommended when you have a better thing that is called `'Binding'`

Comment: So this should go into the VM I assume? When/How should I then call the method? And do I need to pre-declare a Model to be able to use this? As I think that would compromise the whole idea of not needing to pre-declare anything to keep things as tidy as possible..

Comment: Are you using MVVM?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo in my first comment, fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for my answer. Its for simple application. I thought you were not using MVVM

Comment: This answer is basically okay, even in MVVM, it just goes in the code-behind of the View, not the ViewModel.  The ViewModel should be accessible via data binding, either by way of the DataContext (meh) or a DependencyObject of the View.

Comment: Right. Thank you (Y)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind your view with a viewmodel then try this:

Your view model:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private string name;
      // Declare the event
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


  public string PersonName
  {
      get { return name; }
      set
      {
          name = value;
          // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
          OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
      }
  }

  // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
```

}

Great, you have set up your view model. Now the view:

XML PersonView.xml:

```
<Grid Name="MyContainer">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonName}" />
  <Button Name="SaveInfoButton" OnClick="SaveInfoButton_Click">Save info</Button>
</Grid>
```

Now that we have indicated with which property the textbox will be bind, lets indicate to the view the model that will use to update the property named `PersonName`. The idea is that when you click over the button, the property `PersonName` of our model `Person` gets updated with the value of the TextBox.

The xml class:

```
public partial class PersonView : UserControl 
{
  private readonly Person Model;

  public PersonView()  
 {

    //Components initialization, etc. etc...


    this.Model = new Person(); 
    this.DataContext = this.Model;  // Here we are binding the model with our view.
 }

 private void SaveInfoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      MessageBox.Show(this.Model.PersonName); // this will print the value of your textbox.
    }

        }
```

Dont know if you noticed, but we didnt have the need of creating a new object when the user click the button. We just use our model and update the model properpies. If you add more textbox to your view, you'll have to added to our viewmodel as well as the given example.

Here is some post that can help you a little bit more(dont have enough time)

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use bindings like this:

```
<TextBox Name="UI1" Text="{Binding Path=Ut1Value}"/>
<TextBox Name="UI2" Text="{Binding Path=Ut2Value}"/>
<Button Source="*ImageSource*" Command="{Binding CreateTheThingCommand}"/>
```

Then in your viewmodel you'll need to have the properties and command for those:

```
private string _ut1Value;
private string _ut2Value;

public string Ut1Value
{
    get
    {
        return _ut1Value;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_ut1Value!= value)
        {
            _ut1Value= value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Ut1Value");
        }
    }
}

public string Ut2Value
{
    get
    {
        return _ut2Value;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_ut2Value!= value)
        {
            _ut2Value= value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Ut2Value");
        }
    }
}


public ICommand CreateTheThingCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(CreateTheThing); }
}

private void CreateTheThing()
{
    Object newObject = new Object(_ut1Value, _ut2Value, false);
    // Do whatever with your new object
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the easy way. However as mentioned in my post, I'd like to refrain from having to create property fields (and thus command fields) for them

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I missed that part in the question.  Out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid properties?

Comment: I want to avoid cluttering the VM with properties and commands. In the future the 2 textboxes will become more, maybe even going over 10. I'm trying to figure out a way where I can just transport them directly into the method where they're needed, as once they are designated to their Object (a custom object created from a model) the values won't be needed anymore. Having to set a property for them just feels very extensive.

Comment: Okay, is there only ever going to be one button to create the object?  If so I don't think it would be too cluttered to use the binding & command to create the object, then reference each text box's .Text property directly without storing it as a property.  When you add the next text box you'll just have to add its .Text property to the call to the object's constructor in the command.

Comment: yes, it's all relying on just one button, what you mention does sound like a solid solution to me. I do want to point out that the button calls a method where the object is created, but where the object is also immediately put to use and put into an IEnumerable. I don't know if that compromises your solution, because I'd be supergrateful if you could show me a quick example as to what it would look like?

Comment: Updated my answer with what I believe you're asking about the IEnumerable.  If you need to add to an existing one you could have an IList instead and call .Add(newObject); in the command.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120970/discussion-between-ciphra-and-brendan).

Comment: For anyone that comes across this answer, I reverted my answer back to the original, we realized in our chat that it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you need at least two ViewModel objects:

1. One to present the data from an existing object.  This would be, essentially, what you have already.
2. A container ViewModel.  This encapsulates the behaviours of the `IEnumerable` collection of objects, including the functionality required to `Add` a new object.

The container ViewModel would have the properties that you are struggling with, plus the `CreateObject` command, along with an `IEnumerable` (`ObservableCollection`) property to hold the existing ViewModel objects.

In your View, you would have one control to present the data in an existing ViewModel object, and a second control with a `ListView` (or similar) control to display the existing view controls and the set of `TextBox` controls, plus the button to create a new object (and add it to the list).

This would also allow you to add 'remove', 'sort', etc. functionality to the container ViewModel, without having to change the existing ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

A way to accomplish a scalable solution with minimal lines of code, would be to create hold a list of items you bind to in the view model.
This way you can use an ItemsControl in the UI to display a textbox for each item:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Item> Items {get;} = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Value = "UI1" },
        new Item { Value = "UI2" },
    };

    public class Item
    {
        public string Value {get;set;}
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<Button Content="Commit" Margin="5" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
```

You can then create the object either from a click event or command:

```
private void OnCallCreateObject()
{
   Object newObject = new Object(Items[0], Items[1], false);
}
```

The downside is that the order of the items is not explicit, so either you need to assume that the indexed order is correct, or order them manually.